# Specify which Nunit category to run in nunit project

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I have an nunit-project file that is being executed automatically. Though, there are many categories in the dll and I only want only some of them to be executed. Formerly, I have called the nunit file as follows:
`C:\Path\To\nunit-console.exe C:\Path\To\My\nunit-project.nunit /include:MyCategory`
So only "MyCategory" would be executed. Unfortunatly, I no longer have the ability to call this via /include because of an automated process that does not allow this feature. So now my question: Can I specify the category/ies to that should be executed within the .nunit file, or within the config file?

Thanks in advance and best regards :)
Freddie

I have tried to ask google but I haven't found anything helpful :( I had hoped to find something like
MyCategory or something similar

Comment: The answer will depend entirely on what software is being used to run the command automatically. (You should edit your question to specify that info rather than doing reply or comment.)